# how can i attach an MDF file to a server with the same LDF name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `.MDF` backup of a database. I need some information from this `.MDF`.

When I try to attach this `.MDF`, it requires the log file with which it shipped.

I don't need the log file, but it insists on the `.LDF` file.

I tried to point it to the same log file with which it shipped, but I am getting the error:

[image]

(Since it is in use by the current version of the database.)

I am unable to attach it to a different server because it was originally on a SQL Server 2012, and that is my only SQL Server 2012 server.

How do I reattach the `.MDF` without the `.LDF`?

I am adding a text version in case somebody else is searching for a solution to this issue:

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
>   Unable to open the physical file "D:\SQL Logs....Custom_log.ldf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
>   File activation failure. The physical file name "D:\SQL Logs....Custom_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
>   The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.
>
> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Could not open new database 'TestDb'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I actually do not need to attach `.MDF` file if I don't have to. I only need to read one table from there.

Comment: i have already tried all 3 suggestions here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/26/sql-server-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file-in-database/

Comment: It appears you did not detach it properly, therefore the file is not in a consistent state and you cannot reattach it. A MDF file is not a backup. If you need a backup, run a backup command. Can you explain what you mean by "Since it is in use by the current version of the database"? Do you mean you are trying to attach a MDF file and a LDF ALREADY EXISTS by the same name and is in use? if this is the case why don't you try renaming your MDF and attaching it so it doesn't try and create a LDF of the same name?

Comment: @ElectricLlama i have a database, and I have an old MDF of the database. i'm trying to grab a table from the old MDF. does that make sense?

Comment: Does the file `D:\SQL Logs\....Custom_log.ldf` already exist on the SQL Server _before_ you try to attach the MDF?

Comment: You definitely need to attach the MDF to a database server to get the table out, so lets focus on attaching the MDF without an error.

Comment: Do you know the circumstances in which the MDF file was captured? was it detached first?

Comment: I probably means that this MDF default log file already exists and is used by another database. I don't know any way to avoid this error but a `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` should attach it correctly even if it reports an error.

Answer (score 7):

if you  use  2012
 use `"FOR ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG"`

```
  CREATE DATABASE [XXXdatabasname] ON 
( FILENAME = N'databaseXXXFilePath.mdf' )
 FOR ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG
```

Comment: It worked for me on SQL Server 2014 express edition I was getting following error   
  "The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure."

Answer (score -2):

You can attach an MDF file without it's corresponding LDF file.  To do this, I would use  [sp_attach_single_file_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385.aspx)

Comment: Unable to open the physical file ".._log.ldf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
File activation failure. The physical file name ".._log.ldf" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.
Could not open new database 'TestDb'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.